# how to run SmartStore.NET in visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

how start smartstore.net in visual studio localhost without any error

i download github code and open project file from

SmartStoreNET-3.x\src\SmartStoreNET.sln
The download link https://github.com/smartstoreag/SmartStoreNET

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I use visual studio 2015 enterprise edition and windows 10.
First, you must be change the "Solution Configuration" to Debug mode, and second change the "Solution Plataform" to Any CPU.
This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this integration/configuration procedure trying to get a local instance of SmartStore.NET up and running with demo data. I was able to get there eventually, but the development environment setup was by far the most tricky.

I would suggest starting with these two links:

http://docs.smartstore.com/display/SMNET30/Installing+SmartStore.NET
http://docs.smartstore.com/display/SMNET30/How+to+build+SmartStore.NET

I have a hunch you're issue may be your development environment configuration is not fully correct. Check out this page for more details about requirements:

**Technology and Prerequisites**
http://docs.smartstore.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35555597

*NOTE: they reference ASP.NET 4.5.1 but I had to use 4.61 to take advantage of some newer features in C# 7.0 - Tuples, and several others)

Probably the most significant discovery I found was their were dependency issues when trying to restore the NuGet packages referenced in the solution. I had to go through this process maybe 4 or 5 times to finally get the app running locally.

Once all of this was complete, getting it working in 2015 required little effort.

I would also suggest narrowing your question to more specific problems. (that's just me)